# Can I use SOAPUI testing tool for automated testing of a purely web-based application?

Tags: testing, web-applications, automation, soapui

If I am that stupid to ask this question, please excuse me.

Anyway, I have searched and found out some notes about the tool which I have given below.

> SoapUI is a complete and automated testing solution. In a single test
>   environment, it provides industry-leading technologies and standards
>   support, from SOAP- and REST-based Web services, to JMS enterprise
>   messaging layers, databases, Rich Internet Applications, and much
>   more.

From the above content, whether we can assume that it will be well-suited for web-based automation testing perfectly? It would be good if you could share some relevant info on the same.

Thanks :)-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best automated testing tool for web applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79733/best-automated-testing-tool-for-web-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would question as to why you want to use soapUI for web UI testing? For web UI testing i would recommend using some other tool like selenium.

As clarified in my comment below, it would seem that you can make soapUI and Selenium work together. See http://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/selenium-soapui-can-they-work-together/ for details.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But, it has been said everywhere that SOAPUI is better used for testing Web services and related applications and not generally for pure web-applications. What is your comment on tha?

Comment: I have been working with soapUI since the last 6 years and i am yet to use it for website testing. soapUI does a lot more than just web services but i would not recommend it as a web ui testing tool. On second thoughts, my statement may not be entirely true as mentioned in this [blog](http://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/selenium-soapui-can-they-work-together/) by Pradeep Bishnoi that soapUI and Selenium can work together and if you can make that happen then Yes, I guess you could use soapUI for web UI testing. Does that help?

Comment: That said, I am really curious as to why you are even thinking of using soapUI for web UI testing?

Comment: No. I just wanted to compare Selenium with SOAPUI. Also in search of a best tool for web-application testing.

Comment: Selenium is really awesome but if you or your company has the money then QTP is simply awesome. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79733/best-automated-testing-tool-for-web-applications

Comment: Please update the URL http://www.soapui.org/Web-and-HTTP/getting-started.html as it is no-more valid or update the answer.